# How to use Companion object in the main class

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, companion-object

in the below 2 posted examples, i am trying to convert the java code to kotlin code.

the kotlin code does not work and IntelliJ says that I should use companion object.

please let me know how to correct this error.

**code_kotlin***

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 class MyApplication {
 }

 fun main(args: Array<String>) {
 SpringApplication.run(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
 }
```

**codeJava**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 public class MyApplication {  
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
 }       
 }
```

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Include `main` function inside Application class, as Java code does:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 class MyApplication {

   fun main(args: Array<String>) {
     SpringApplication.run(MyApplication::class.java, *args)
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java or C#, Kotlin doesn’t have static members or member functions. Kotlin recommends to simply use package-level functions instead. For more detail you can get help from [link](https://medium.com/@agrawalsuneet/companion-object-in-kotlin-5251e03d6423). You can call companion object like-

```
class YourClassName{

    companion object {
         //write what you want to make static
    }  
}
```